# Cancel event in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'd like to cancel the `MouseEvent` that is fired on `object:moving` in fabric.js, to prevent all the actions when some condition is met. I tried to set `cancelBubble = true` or simply `return false;` but with no success. Any ideas?

Sample fiddle with some event:
http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/S9sLu/

Answer (score 1):

Mouse `mouse:moving` event is continuosly fired while mouse pointer is on canvas. But by checking `event.target` you can check if that's a generic or object related move.

```
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(options) { 
    if(options.target) {
    //suppress event handlers here
 }
});
```